# Unitary Operators in Hilbert's space are arcwise connected using functional calculus

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This is a follow up question on: [unitary operators in Hilbert's space are arcwise connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3343700/unitary-operators-in-hilberts-space-are-arcwise-connected).

I see that Theorem 2.12 of Murphy's book shows that if $\sigma(u) \ne \mathbb{T}$, then there exists $a \in A_{sa}$ such that $u =e^{ia}$ using functional calculus.

I wonder how to continue the argument and show that the unitary operators are arcwise connected as https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3348044/836719 has suggested.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$
  \text{lg}:S^1\to[0,2\pi),
  $$
defined by $\text{lg}(e^{i\theta})=\theta$, for all $\theta \in  [0,2\pi)$, is Borel measurable on $\sigma (u)$, so  the Borel
functional calculus provides a meaning to $\text{lg}(u)$, and one has that
$$
  e^{i\, \text{lg}(u)}=u.
  $$

Comment: A nice remark that can be added here: the same can be done in any von Neumann algebra, since Borel functional calculus can be performed.