# The set of unitary operators on a complex separable Hilbert space is connected

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In my functional analysis class I was given a problem:

Let $H$ be complex separable Hilbert space. Prove that the set of unitary operators on $H$ is connected (as topological space with operator norm).

I know the [proof that unitary operators are path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074078), so they are connected. This proof is not short. And I wonder if it is possible to prove that unitary operators are connected without proving path-connectedness? It would give shorter proof of this problem.

I do not have any ideas how to prove connectedness of unitary operators without proving path-connectedness, so any hints are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is even [contractible, by Kuiper's theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938365900674).

Comment: What were you taught recently in said class? Just to see what kind of argument(s) your teacher is expecting you to use to show such a result by yourself.

Comment: @BrunoB it is basic functional analysis course. last facts in my course: we have discussed representation of self-adjoint operator in complex separable Hilbert space, also the projecture measures (only definition).

Comment: @AnneBauval that's impressive, but  it is more complicated fact that path-connectedness. My task is to prove connectedness and I wonder if I can do this in easier way.